# Deploying a java program

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a java application that I created.  Now I want to give it to my friend?  How do I create a deploy version of this that they can run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest for you is to export the program as a "Runnable JAR file". Your friend then does this from the command line:

```
java -jar MyApp.jar
```

Probably the easiest way for your friend is if you take the above jar file and deploy it with [WebStart](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/deployment/webstart/). It's cross platform. Your friend simply uses their web browser to browse to the web page where the application is hosted and clicks on a link.

Answer (score 0):

Create a JAR file (it's in the export menu), and send that to them. JAR files contain all the classes in a Java application, and a manifest that specifies things like which one is the main class. If the application depends on other 3rdparty libraries, you'll need to include them as well; it's possible to bundle them in the JAR file, but it's non-trivial

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](http://www.vogella.de/articles/Eclipse/article.html#firstjava_export) is what you are looking for. Basically make it into a self-executing jar and run. It gets more complicated if you have other dependencies besides the standard API in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Create a jar file, and put the following info in your manifest file

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: lib.jar 
Main-Class: mypackage.MyClassWithMainMethod
```